# Has API been written for SpatiaLite for Cordova?

Tags: javascript, spatialite, cordova

I am creating an app in which I will be creating an AutoCAD model for a 3 floor building at my college.

I'll be importing this model as a spatial object into my javascript app - then wrap it with cordova/ionic and use it on iphone.

I want the user to be able to tap starting and ending points on my map object (not geospatial, just an object) and the shortest path to get there will be highlighted.

I have got SQlite working on the javascript / cordova app.

An API was written for SQLite for cordova.

Is there one for Spatialite as well?

Comment: SpatiaLite can easily be called from javascript (its just sqlite functions). Support on iphone may be marginal though - I've not tried it recently. The question about "export" doesn't make any sense to me with the information you've provided. What kind of CAD model are you building? What tool? What is the goal of the export (e.g. a picture or a routable network)? How are you planning to do the routing? There are many options, and your question is both very broad and some-what leaning to opinion based answers.

Comment: Perhaps take the tour (see link under help, top right) and edit your question to contain just a single question.

Comment: I edited my question. I think the issue is that I am not sure how spatialite works. If sqlite works on javascript, I am guessing I dont need anymore APIs because spatialite is already included. Am I correct?